# crashlyticsのUnitySDKにてクラッシュさせずにログを通知したい

Tags: unity3d, fabric

英語板の方でも質問したのですが情報が得られないのでこちらでも質問させてください。

### ●質問

下記の参照ページを参考に、UnityのC＃で致命的ではないログを送信していますが、
ダッシュボードで通知を確認できません。

問題点があれば教えていただけないでしょうか？

また、クラッシュすることなくログに通知する方法の知見をお持ちの方は教えていただけないでしょうか？

### ■テストソースコード

```
public static void SendCrashMessagePlusCustomStackTrace（文字列名、文字列の理由、文字列stackTraceString）
{
    Crashlytics.RecordCustomException（name、reason、stackTraceString）;
    Crashlytics.ThrowNonFatal（）;
}
```

### ■参照ページ

https://docs.fabric.io/unity/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html

### ■開発環境

Unity 5.6.3 p1